# Resizing the graph of a function with radicals , Why?

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, syntax

I am trying to graph this function
$c(t)=\frac{2-\sqrt{t+3}}{1-t}$

using this code, to see its behavior at infinity.
I need that in the vertical axis appears the value when $t->1$ (The graphs sometimes have 2 cut-off lines when the values are too high, I don't know how to do it) that is 1/4 , and in the axis appears c(t), and if it is possible to give a better representation of the curve.

```
c[t_]:=\frac{2-\sqrt{t+3}}{1-t}
Plot[c[t], {t, 0, 100000000000}, AxesLabel -> {t, c[t]}]
```

please help me

Comment: Try this: `c[t_] := (2 - Sqrt[t + 3])/(1 - t); LogLogPlot[
 c[t], {t, 0, 100000000000}, AxesLabel -> {t, c[t]}]` . Have fun!

Comment: Try also this: `Show[{
  Plot[c[t], {t, 0, 2}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["t", 16, Italic, Black], 
     Style["c(t)", 16, Italic, Black]}],
  Graphics[{Gray, Dashed, Line[{{1, 0.235}, {1, 0.270}}], 
    Line[{{0, 0.25}, {2, 0.25}}]}]
  }]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

c[t_] = (2 - Sqrt[t + 3])/(1 - t);
```

Re "to see its behavior at infinity"

[`Asymptotic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Asymptotic.html) was introduced in version 12.1

```
c2[t_] = Asymptotic[c[t], t -> Infinity]

(* 1/Sqrt[t] *)
```

Or using [`Series`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html)

```
c3[t_] = Series[c[t], {t, Infinity, 1}] // Normal

(* -(2/t) + 1/Sqrt[t] *)

LogLogPlot[{c[t], c2[t], c3[t]}, {t, 1, 10^6},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.4, .35}]]
```

[image]